# I want to find the 'N/A' value and update it with the next value

Tags: sql, t-sql

I have a table wherein alot of values are 'N/A' there.  i want to update it with the next non 'N/A' value.

my table:

```
col1  || column2   || Column3   


N/A   ||  ACT0001   || ACT0002


ACT0004   || N/A   || ABT0003


N/A   || N/A   || AND0009
```

output:

Column4

```
ACT001

ABT003

AND009
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: What have you tried so far? And are only 3 columns in your database or it will be more?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about this:

```
UPDATE Table
SET Col4 = COALESCE(NULLIF(Col1, 'N/A'), NULLIF(Col2, 'N/A'), NULLIF(Col3, 'N/A'))
```

You can remove the `NULIIF` statement if `Col3` is going always to have value or add additional criteria if all of the values are 'N/A':

```
 COALESCE(NULLIF(Col1, 'N/A'), NULLIF(Col2, 'N/A'), NULLIF(Col3, 'N/A'), 'No value found')
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure I understood you, maybe something like that?

```
UPDATE YourTable t
SET t.col4 = CASE WHEN t.col1 = 'N/A' THEN
                                           CASE WHEN t.col2 <> 'N/A' THEN t.col2
                                                ELSE t.col3
                                           END
                  WHEN t.col2 = 'N/A' THEN t.col3 
             END
```

Comment: Thank you this is what i was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

```
     UPDATE YourTable SET COl4 = CASE WHEN Col1 = 'N/A' THEN  
     COALESCE(Col1,Col2) WHEN Col2 = 'N/A' THEN COALESCE(Col2,Col3) ELSE Col3     
     END
```